# Display elements on button click in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am new to React and I have to display data about some books that are loaded from a database, as I do in render(). I want to do that when I click my "All Books" button. What should I write in the getAllBooks function to do that instead of writing the code in render()? I really can't find the right way to do it. Thank you!
    ,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import BookStore from './BookStore'
import {EventEmitter} from 'fbemitter'

const emitter= new EventEmitter()
const store= new BookStore(emitter)

class BookList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state= {
            books: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        store.getAll()
        emitter.addListener('BOOK LOAD', ()=>{
            this.setState({books: store.content})
        })

        this.getAllBooks = this.getAllBooks.bind(this);
    }

    getAllBooks(){

    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            <div>
            <h3>The Books:</h3>
            <br></br>
            <div>
            {
            this.state.books.map((b)=>
            <div>{b.title +' by '+ b.author}</div>
            )
            }
            </div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="All Books" onClick={this.getAllBooks}/>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default BookList
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code that is in render?

Comment: Nothing, it works fine, but I want to execute that when clicking my button.

Comment: just move your code there

Comment: This might seem the obvious way to do it, but it doesn't work. And I don't know exactly how to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the code that is in your render function to `getAllBooks` but you should also move your binding to the `constructor`.